# GCC with XCode command line tools doesn't work

Tags: xcode, gcc, g++, command-line-tool

I've installed command lien tools in XCode. But still get this issue :

```
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-arch"
```

So I think the new gcc wrapper isn't working. How can i find the newly installed gcc ?

Comment: GCC that comes with Xcode is ***ooooooold.*** Use `clang` instead.

Comment: What version? `gcc -version`? Did you ever install another gcc? What is the command you're trying to run? Did you try `which gcc`?